# Python Row Iteration - row values = dicationary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

There is a column in my dataframe where each row value is a dictionary. I am trying to iterate over each row, only pulling out certain values of the dictionary each time.

Here is a screenshot of a  [sample dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICwcz.png).

In this example, for each row how would we extract the 'visits' from the totals column?

This is what I came up with... is it the cleanest way?

```
for row in train.head().itertuples():
      print(ast.literal_eval(row.totals)['visits'])
```

Comment: Search for json_normalize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apply a function on the specified column, in the function you extract and return that value.

```
import ast

df.totals.apply(lambda x: x['visits']) # if the row value is a dict

df.totals.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)['visits']) # if the row value is a string
```

Comment: So I realized the row values are strings that look like dictionary, which is why my original code uses ast.literal_eval to convert it to a true dictionary. How do you incorporate that into the lambda statement above?

Comment: @ZakRaySick I added an example where the row value is a string